# Why does CORS ask new domain and not original domain?

Tags: networking, browser, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I believe I am finally grok-ing CORS and its motivations.

In brief, I understand that a script originating from **original.com** attempting to *request* a resource *from* **other.com** is potentially risky (for all parties: user, original.com and other.com) due to information leaking; thats the motivation behind CORS. My question is not about this.

CORS mandates that **other.com** opts-in/agrees to the request from the scripts that originates from **original.com**.

It took a while to grok because I had a certain intuition I had to go against. My intuition was that its supposed to be **original.com** (and *not* **other.com**) that had to opt-in/agree to the cross-origin request.

The line of thinking was that **original.com** is the domain that the user trusts (after all, user went to **original.com** in the first place). Hence the browser (enforcer of CORS) should trust whomever the user trusts.

e.g.

If **original.com** says to trust *other.com*, *ads.com* and/or *tracker.com* then go ahead and allow requests to them. But if subsequently *ads.com* returns a script that requests something from *shadows.com* (whom **original.com** does *not* trust) then block it.

Currently, CORS will cause the browser to ask **shadows.com** if it accepts a request from **original.com**. And I imagine **shadows.com** to be a villain in a leather armchair saying 'why yes, absolutely' >:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short and a bit simplified, it's because data is downloaded from the other domain. In your example, other.com holds the data and can decide who (what origins) it shares that data with.

The kind of trust that you are mentioning is by the way also present. When a user visits original.com in the example above, he trusts that original.com will only make him download stuff from domains deemed ok to download data from by developers of original.com. However, whether those other sources (other.com, etc.) want to serve a request when it comes from a user visiting a different site (original.com), it's a decision for the other domains to make.